# Datatables warning(table id='inventory') cannot reinitialize data table even if there's only one initialization

Tags: jquery, datatables

I don't know what I'm doing wrong! I keep receiving that error when there's only one initialization of that datatable. Anyone had the same problems?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.display').DataTable();
    $('#inventory').DataTable({
        "aoColumnDefs": [{"bVisible": false, "aTargets": [0]}]
    });
}
```

Comment: does your table id="inventory" have the class table.display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.display').DataTable();
    var invTbl = $('#inventory').DataTable();
    invTbl.column(0).visible(false);
});
```